# SVG angle rotation by mousemove/touchmove bug

Tags: jquery, svg, rotation, angle, touchmove

I want to rotate svg circulars by mousemove/touchmove with one point finger.

I tried many js scripts (for ex. [Touchy Wheel Demo](http://hotstudio.github.io/touchy/examples/wheel.html) and [Rotate Dial Demo](http://kaisarcode.com/javascript-rotate-dial)) and their examples works perfect, but when I try my example I always see two bugs:

1. Rotation works only in down part of circular, in top part - it's reverse rotate.
2. Rotation works very slowly (in demo wheels strongly follow mouse/finger).

**My Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0L87uabc/8/** (plz see how it work on [author's demo page](http://kaisarcode.com/javascript-rotate-dial) before)

Also i try this simple example -result is similar to above:

```
var dragging = false
$(function() {
    var circles = ['circle-l1', 'circle-l2', 'circle-l3', 'circle-l4', 'circle-l5', 'circle-l6', 'circle-l7'];
    $.each(circles, function(ind, val) {
        var target = $('#'+val)
        target.mousedown(function() {
            dragging = true
        })
        $(document).mouseup(function() {
            dragging = false
        })
        target.mousemove(function(e) {
            if (dragging) {
                var mouse_x = e.pageX;
                var mouse_y = e.pageY;
                var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - 10, mouse_y - 10);
                var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
                target.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Domo2: https://jsfiddle.net/0L87uabc/10/

Can you explain, why my svg doesn't rotate correctly and how to fix it (or you know best script for this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to substract your current pointer position from the center of the circle to get the degree of the pointer relative to the center.
both values need to be in the same coordinate system, so you have to transform your pointer position to the targets (parentNode) coordinate system.

```js
var dragging = false
$(function() {
    var circles = ['circle-l1', 'circle-l2', 'circle-l3', 'circle-l4', 'circle-l5', 'circle-l6', 'circle-l7'];
    $.each(circles, function(ind, val) {
        var target = $('#'+val)
        target.mousedown(function() {
            dragging = true
        })
        $(document).mouseup(function() {
            dragging = false
        })
        target.mousemove(function(e) {
            if (dragging) {
                var ctm=target[0].parentNode.getScreenCTM()

                var p=document.getElementById("rus-front").createSVGPoint()

                p.x=e.clientX
                p.y=e.clientY
                p=p.matrixTransform(ctm.inverse())

                var mouse_x = e.pageX;
                var mouse_y = e.pageY;
                var radians = Math.atan2(1990 - p.x , 1900 - p.y);
                var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
                target.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
            }
     });
    });
});
```

```css
html, body, #circular {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#circular {
 position: relative;
 text-align: left;
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 padding-left: 7%;
}
 #circular svg {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
     width: auto;
 }
 #circular [id^=circle-l] {
  transform-origin: center center;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 #circular #circle-l1 {
  transform-origin: 52% 50%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circular"><svg version="1.1" id="rus-front" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="4050px" height="3940px" viewBox="0 0 4050 3940" enable-background="new 0 0 4050 3940" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="circle-l7" opacity="0.9">
 <g>
  <defs>
   <rect id="SVGID_1_" x="321.191" y="211.45" width="3361.599" height="3361.596"/>
  </defs>
  <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
   <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  overflow="visible"/>
  </clipPath>
  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" fill="#062D84" d="M3648.641,1553.511c-22.083-107.917-55.034-214.069-97.939-315.505
   c-42.125-99.594-94.263-195.653-154.968-285.508c-60.128-89.001-129.181-172.693-205.241-248.753
   c-76.058-76.059-159.75-145.112-248.752-205.239c-89.854-60.705-185.914-112.844-285.508-154.969
   c-101.436-42.904-207.587-75.855-315.505-97.938c-110.731-22.659-224.699-34.148-338.738-34.148
   c-114.04,0-228.007,11.489-338.739,34.148c-107.917,22.083-214.068,55.034-315.504,97.938
   c-99.594,42.125-195.654,94.264-285.508,154.969c-89.001,60.127-172.694,129.18-248.753,205.239
   c-76.059,76.06-145.112,159.752-205.24,248.753c-60.705,89.855-112.843,185.914-154.968,285.508
   c-42.904,101.436-75.855,207.588-97.938,315.505c-22.66,110.731-34.148,224.699-34.148,338.737
   c0,114.041,11.488,228.008,34.148,338.738c22.083,107.918,55.034,214.068,97.938,315.505
   c42.125,99.595,94.263,195.653,154.968,285.507c60.128,89.002,129.181,172.694,205.24,248.754
   c76.059,76.058,159.752,145.111,248.753,205.239c89.854,60.705,185.914,112.843,285.508,154.968
   c101.436,42.905,207.587,75.856,315.504,97.939c110.732,22.659,224.699,34.147,338.739,34.147
   c114.039,0,228.007-11.488,338.738-34.147c107.918-22.083,214.069-55.034,315.505-97.939
   c99.594-42.125,195.653-94.263,285.508-154.968c89.002-60.128,172.694-129.181,248.752-205.239
   c76.061-76.06,145.113-159.752,205.241-248.754c60.705-89.854,112.843-185.912,154.968-285.507
   c42.905-101.437,75.856-207.587,97.939-315.505c22.659-110.73,34.146-224.697,34.146-338.738
   C3682.787,1778.209,3671.3,1664.242,3648.641,1553.511z M2259.281,3514.882c-86.615,13.965-175.199,21.046-263.291,21.046
   c-67.508,0-135.711-4.184-202.811-12.445c-32.126-1.359-57.291-27.626-57.291-59.798c0-33.009,26.855-59.863,59.864-59.863
   c4.107,0,8.224,0.423,12.323,1.271c64.201,8.121,129.535,12.24,194.187,12.24c79.058,0,158.538-6.093,236.324-18.125
   c4.522-1.082,9.147-1.629,13.743-1.629c32.457,0,58.864,26.405,58.864,58.862
   C2311.194,3486.248,2288.896,3511.371,2259.281,3514.882z M2001.99,3387.884c-826.017,0-1495.636-669.618-1495.636-1495.636
   S1175.974,396.612,2001.99,396.612c826.018,0,1495.636,669.619,1495.636,1495.636S2828.008,3387.884,2001.99,3387.884z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g id="circle-l6" opacity="0.9">
 <g>
  <defs>
   <rect id="SVGID_3_" x="504.111" y="394.469" width="2995.759" height="2995.558"/>
  </defs>
  <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
   <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  overflow="visible"/>
  </clipPath>
  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#6250CC" d="M2003.554,3390.027c-100.32-0.001-201.47-10.251-300.639-30.465
   c-198.086-40.374-382.338-118.337-547.644-231.722c-79.449-54.496-154.03-117.105-221.672-186.089
   c-66.997-68.327-127.773-143.501-180.638-223.434c-52.865-79.932-98.255-165.28-134.91-253.676
   c-37.007-89.249-65.431-182.384-84.483-276.82c-39.643-196.496-39.271-396.564,1.105-594.649
   c35.365-173.511,99.97-337.23,192.018-486.609c88.944-144.342,201.223-271.788,333.718-378.799
   c131.429-106.151,278.554-188.84,437.287-245.771c161.934-58.08,331.079-87.528,502.734-87.528
   c100.312,0,201.462,10.249,300.639,30.463c198.085,40.376,382.339,118.34,547.643,231.725
   c79.448,54.497,154.028,117.106,221.669,186.089c66.997,68.326,127.773,143.5,180.638,223.434
   c52.866,79.936,98.256,165.285,134.908,253.678c37.006,89.242,65.43,182.378,84.483,276.821
   c39.642,196.498,39.269,396.567-1.106,594.65c-35.365,173.51-99.969,337.227-192.017,486.607
   c-88.943,144.343-201.221,271.789-333.716,378.8c-131.427,106.149-278.551,188.839-437.285,245.77
   c-161.927,58.077-331.064,87.525-502.715,87.525H2003.554z M2597.964,2868.633c-5.396,0-10.772,1.368-15.55,3.957l-81.45,44.149
   c-7.677,4.16-13.273,11.062-15.761,19.435c-2.483,8.369-1.561,17.209,2.6,24.887l123.196,233.408
   c5.718,10.546,16.741,17.101,28.765,17.101c5.396,0,10.771-1.367,15.544-3.955l81.453-44.149
   c7.678-4.16,13.274-11.062,15.761-19.434c2.485-8.371,1.563-17.21-2.598-24.888l-123.197-233.411
   C2621.01,2875.188,2609.988,2868.633,2597.964,2868.633 M2001.029,784.633c-126.831,0-251.81,21.764-371.463,64.686
   c-117.289,42.075-226,103.185-323.113,181.632c-97.899,79.082-180.856,173.262-246.566,279.923
   c-68.004,110.384-115.724,231.362-141.836,359.572c-29.807,146.358-30.058,294.175-0.747,439.345
   c14.088,69.772,35.1,138.58,62.452,204.511c27.091,65.307,60.637,128.361,99.706,187.414
   c39.07,59.054,83.982,114.588,133.489,165.062c49.983,50.958,105.093,97.207,163.799,137.461
   c122.142,83.752,258.285,141.332,404.642,171.14c73.223,14.912,147.9,22.474,221.956,22.474
   c126.83,0,251.808-21.763,371.463-64.687c117.289-42.074,226-103.185,323.112-181.632
   c97.901-79.082,180.855-173.263,246.564-279.923c68.004-110.384,115.726-231.36,141.836-359.57
   c29.807-146.358,30.059-294.176,0.748-439.346c-14.088-69.777-35.1-138.585-62.452-204.513
   c-27.092-65.306-60.636-128.361-99.706-187.413c-39.064-59.047-83.977-114.581-133.488-165.063
   c-49.982-50.957-105.092-97.206-163.799-137.461c-122.143-83.753-258.285-141.332-404.644-171.14
   C2149.766,792.194,2075.091,784.633,2001.029,784.633"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g id="circle-l5" opacity="0.9">
 <g>
  <defs>
   
    <rect id="SVGID_5_" x="892.197" y="782.456" transform="matrix(-0.6474 -0.7622 0.7622 -0.6474 1855.9 4643.1074)" width="2219.588" height="2219.584"/>
  </defs>
  <clipPath id="SVGID_6_">
   <use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_"  overflow="visible"/>
  </clipPath>
  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_6_)" fill="#600875" d="M1156.158,2610.723c-96.975-114.171-168.693-243.922-213.164-385.649
   c-21.373-68.118-36.2-138.737-44.064-209.897c-7.79-70.483-8.821-142.11-3.065-212.892
   c5.756-70.782,18.346-141.301,37.422-209.599c19.259-68.954,45.3-136.25,77.4-200.019
   c66.788-132.68,158.534-249.137,272.691-346.136c114.17-97.012,243.927-168.762,385.665-213.257
   c68.122-21.385,138.747-36.22,209.913-44.092c70.488-7.798,142.123-8.835,212.911-3.083
   c70.789,5.751,141.315,18.339,209.621,37.414c68.962,19.258,136.266,45.3,200.043,77.402
   c132.695,66.792,249.166,158.548,346.177,272.718l0.116,0.136c96.978,114.167,168.699,243.916,213.17,385.642
   c21.375,68.118,36.2,138.737,44.065,209.898c7.791,70.484,8.819,142.111,3.065,212.892
   c-5.756,70.783-18.347,141.303-37.423,209.603c-19.261,68.954-45.302,136.25-77.404,200.02
   c-66.788,132.682-158.536,249.14-272.693,346.14c-114.17,97.012-243.925,168.761-385.663,213.256
   c-68.124,21.385-138.749,36.219-209.914,44.093c-70.49,7.797-142.123,8.834-212.912,3.083
   c-70.789-5.754-141.316-18.341-209.622-37.415c-68.961-19.259-136.265-45.3-200.041-77.402
   c-132.695-66.792-249.166-158.548-346.177-272.719L1156.158,2610.723z M2715.987,1280.863
   c-82-96.535-180.455-174.122-292.626-230.607c-108.346-54.557-224.866-87.234-346.322-97.121
   c-121.456-9.888-241.726,3.511-357.47,39.825c-119.831,37.597-229.538,98.239-326.073,180.24
   c-96.536,82.001-174.123,180.454-230.608,292.626c-54.557,108.347-87.233,224.866-97.123,346.323
   c-9.887,121.456,3.512,241.726,39.827,357.47c37.597,119.831,98.238,229.538,180.239,326.073
   c82.002,96.537,180.455,174.124,292.627,230.608c108.347,54.558,224.866,87.234,346.322,97.123
   c121.457,9.886,241.727-3.513,357.471-39.828c119.831-37.597,229.538-98.238,326.074-180.239s174.123-180.455,230.607-292.626
   c54.558-108.347,87.234-224.866,97.122-346.321c9.888-121.457-3.512-241.727-39.826-357.471
   C2858.63,1487.107,2797.989,1377.399,2715.987,1280.863 M932.392,1981.417c0.631,10.614,4.611,20.516,11.509,28.636
   c8.432,9.922,20.224,15.967,33.201,17.022c12.979,1.053,25.591-3.009,35.514-11.441c11.87-10.086,18.233-25.402,17.022-40.968
   l-0.111-1.425l0.168-0.011c-9.578-113.265,0.454-226.354,29.828-336.173l-0.136-0.038l0.339-1.346
   c3.85-15.271,0.078-31.536-10.091-43.507c-8.44-9.931-20.23-15.977-33.209-17.031c-12.978-1.055-25.589,3.008-35.512,11.439
   c-7.291,6.196-12.555,14.317-15.224,23.483l-0.39,1.342l-0.029-0.008c-32.236,120.369-43.348,244.352-33.031,368.553l0.035-0.003
   L932.392,1981.417z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<path id="circle-l4" fill="#E21E26" d="M2001.792,2834.114c-33.627,0-67.734-1.843-101.375-5.478
 c-125.319-13.536-245.186-51.739-356.269-113.548c-111.077-61.809-206.732-143.523-284.306-242.877
 c-74.922-95.964-129.908-204.257-163.431-321.871c-33.52-117.617-43.885-238.627-30.809-359.668
 c13.535-125.316,51.738-245.18,113.547-356.266c61.821-111.09,143.537-206.745,242.88-284.306
 c95.962-74.925,204.255-129.911,321.87-163.431c84.49-24.079,171.398-36.288,258.312-36.288c33.621,0,67.722,1.842,101.357,5.475
 c125.315,13.539,245.18,51.744,356.266,113.554c111.088,61.811,206.741,143.527,284.305,242.879
 c74.927,95.962,129.913,204.254,163.432,321.869c33.52,117.614,43.887,238.624,30.811,359.667
 c-13.537,125.317-51.74,245.184-113.547,356.268c-61.816,111.087-143.531,206.741-242.877,284.305
 c-95.961,74.923-204.254,129.908-321.873,163.43C2175.601,2821.906,2088.698,2834.114,2001.792,2834.114 M2000.197,1254.975
 c-51.842,0-103.776,6.416-154.361,19.07c-82.859,20.729-159.761,57.504-228.573,109.305
 c-71.914,54.133-130.386,121.136-173.79,199.146c-59.259,106.502-86.722,227.296-79.419,349.322
 c7.491,125.146,51.469,244.454,127.179,345.027c51.802,68.819,115.533,125.43,189.422,168.264
 c71.371,41.374,149.164,68.222,231.219,79.798c29.832,4.208,60.082,6.342,89.91,6.343h0.015c51.834,0,103.762-6.416,154.35-19.068
 c82.851-20.728,159.755-57.503,228.574-109.307c71.91-54.135,130.382-121.138,173.789-199.148
 c59.258-106.496,86.72-227.288,79.418-349.32c-7.484-125.133-51.46-244.441-127.174-345.026
 c-51.8-68.813-115.533-125.426-189.425-168.268c-71.373-41.374-149.166-68.221-231.222-79.795
 C2060.272,1257.108,2030.022,1254.975,2000.197,1254.975 M1322.123,1960.018c-0.796,0-1.602,0.061-2.395,0.182l-207.379,31.588
 c-4.887,0.74-9.067,3.645-11.468,7.968c-1.72,3.089-2.346,6.575-1.812,10.08c0.638,4.188,2.865,7.874,6.272,10.38
 c2.744,2.02,5.978,3.087,9.352,3.087c0.805,0,1.619-0.063,2.422-0.185l207.382-31.592c4.883-0.738,9.063-3.644,11.47-7.969
 c1.719-3.089,2.344-6.572,1.81-10.075C1336.606,1965.806,1329.876,1960.018,1322.123,1960.018"/>
<g id="circle-l3" opacity="0.9">
 <g>
  <defs>
   
    <rect id="SVGID_7_" x="1359.715" y="1249.978" transform="matrix(0.0042 -1 1 0.0042 101.4478 3886.3657)" width="1284.55" height="1284.54"/>
  </defs>
  <clipPath id="SVGID_8_">
   <use xlink:href="#SVGID_7_"  overflow="visible"/>
  </clipPath>
  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_8_)" fill="#420351" d="M2387.222,1378.378c-283.801-212.757-686.34-155.166-899.097,128.634
   c-212.759,283.802-155.166,686.346,128.634,899.1c283.802,212.76,686.343,155.166,899.101-128.637
   C2728.614,1993.674,2671.025,1591.134,2387.222,1378.378 M1827.783,2459.995c-11.949,15.937-33.229,20.743-50.551,12.521
   c-51.833-20.053-101.82-47.429-148.475-82.406c-32.185-24.127-61.344-50.792-87.433-79.493
   c-15.5-14.118-18.02-37.974-5.183-55.095c13.637-18.19,39.437-21.882,57.63-8.243c3.044,2.283,5.672,4.911,7.893,7.782
   c22.746,25.08,48.18,48.374,76.281,69.442c40.122,30.079,83.078,53.696,127.622,71.057c4.911,1.322,9.655,3.571,13.97,6.806
   C1837.726,2416.003,1841.419,2441.805,1827.783,2459.995 M1886.993,2393.569c-276.461-63.945-448.74-339.896-384.794-616.359
   c63.945-276.46,339.897-448.739,616.359-384.794c276.458,63.946,448.737,339.896,384.792,616.359
   C2439.406,2285.237,2163.452,2457.515,1886.993,2393.569"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g id="circle-l2" opacity="0.9">
 <g>
  <defs>
   
    <rect id="SVGID_9_" x="1486.775" y="1377.038" transform="matrix(0.2791 -0.9602 0.9602 0.2791 -373.8815 3286.4509)" width="1030.43" height="1030.419"/>
  </defs>
  <clipPath id="SVGID_10_">
   <use xlink:href="#SVGID_9_"  overflow="visible"/>
  </clipPath>
  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_10_)" fill="#EE4723" d="M1505.475,1754.715c18.568-67.027,49.707-128.417,92.553-182.457
   c41.385-52.2,91.893-95.38,150.124-128.348c58.227-32.97,121.241-54.064,187.295-62.696c68.385-8.934,137.046-4.05,204.072,14.517
   c66.957,18.542,128.286,49.638,182.286,92.417c52.158,41.317,95.326,91.743,128.308,149.879
   c32.977,58.135,54.113,121.056,62.818,187.018c9.013,68.286,4.244,136.863-14.18,203.829l-0.25,0.905
   c-18.568,67.026-49.707,128.416-92.551,182.455c-41.385,52.198-91.893,95.381-150.124,128.35
   c-58.229,32.968-121.244,54.061-187.294,62.689c-68.387,8.935-137.049,4.052-204.075-14.514
   c-66.954-18.543-128.285-49.639-182.284-92.418c-52.16-41.313-95.331-91.741-128.308-149.877
   c-32.98-58.134-54.115-121.054-62.821-187.018c-9.011-68.282-4.243-136.859,14.177-203.82L1505.475,1754.715z M1814.624,1971.048
   c0.972-3.53,0.747-7.189-0.65-10.584c-1.669-4.053-4.816-7.217-8.864-8.906c-4.048-1.685-8.508-1.695-12.561-0.029
   l-241.407,99.339c-4.729,1.946-8.224,5.896-9.581,10.834c-0.973,3.53-0.745,7.193,0.654,10.591
   c1.667,4.055,4.81,7.216,8.858,8.904c4.048,1.685,8.507,1.696,12.563,0.027l241.404-99.339
   C1809.771,1979.938,1813.267,1975.987,1814.624,1971.048 M2176.272,1940.152c17.249-62.7-0.518-130.235-46.365-176.256
   c-70.575-70.835-185.62-71.046-256.454-0.479c-22.334,22.25-38.534,49.982-46.844,80.199
   c-17.249,62.702,0.518,130.24,46.362,176.259c34.19,34.315,79.692,53.264,128.129,53.352c48.438,0.09,94.013-18.69,128.329-52.875
   C2151.764,1998.098,2167.963,1970.367,2176.272,1940.152"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g id="circle-l1" opacity="0.9">
 <g>
  <defs>
   <rect id="SVGID_11_" x="1818.64" y="1708.893" width="366.701" height="366.71"/>
  </defs>
  <clipPath id="SVGID_12_">
   <use xlink:href="#SVGID_11_"  overflow="visible"/>
  </clipPath>
  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_12_)" fill="#600875" d="M2001.76,2075.607c-31.688-0.003-63.063-8.355-90.733-24.156
   c-87.78-50.125-118.418-162.321-68.297-250.104c32.564-57.027,93.631-92.453,159.369-92.453c31.683,0,63.058,8.353,90.734,24.157
   c42.525,24.281,73.049,63.668,85.95,110.907c12.899,47.238,6.631,96.672-17.651,139.198
   c-32.563,57.025-93.627,92.452-159.356,92.452H2001.76z M1937.229,1983.269c-9.241,0-17.825,4.979-22.402,12.992
   c-3.413,5.976-4.294,12.923-2.48,19.563c1.813,6.641,6.103,12.177,12.081,15.591c0.832,0.474,1.746,0.925,2.719,1.34
   c22.98,12.237,48.777,18.694,74.648,18.694c12.949,0,25.902-1.588,38.5-4.719c7.924-1.184,14.697-5.813,18.638-12.71
   c3.412-5.976,4.294-12.923,2.48-19.563c-1.813-6.641-6.103-12.176-12.08-15.586c-3.882-2.22-8.286-3.393-12.736-3.393
   c-2.396,0-4.783,0.334-7.097,0.992c-9.037,2.39-18.337,3.6-27.65,3.6c-17.795,0-35.51-4.502-51.231-13.019l-0.149-0.092
   c-0.161-0.103-0.322-0.203-0.488-0.298C1946.089,1984.442,1941.681,1983.269,1937.229,1983.269"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg></div>
```

Comment: Wonderful! What is it 1990 and 1900&? Why this numbers?

Comment: That's the centre of your circles.I could have used BBox to calculate it to more generalise the code, but thought it would be better to keep it simple ;-)

Comment: Thank You! Can you help to save last/current position? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682503/jquery-transform-rotation-how-to-save-last-angle

Answer (score 1):

On the second example:

`var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;`

I changed the `+ 90` to `+ 180` and this allows rotation in the top half. Also, removing `(180 / Math.PI)` from the line above may help you achieve your desired result.

For the speed, you can vary the values on this line:

`Math.atan2(mouse_x - 10, mouse_y - 10);`

I set it to `mouse_x - 100, mouse_y - 100` and it is much faster.

Answer (score -2):

You may able to use the SMIL spec. See if anything here helps [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/).

Comment: Please remember an answer should contain a bit more than just a link.