# jquery resizing a rotated image using mouse (mousemove event)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, resize

i'm trying to create controls that allow me to resize current object(in this case image) using (nw,n,ne,e,se,s,sw,w) controls, when there is no rotation the resizing work perfect otherwise it didn't work, i tried to fix it,i also searched for it, but i ended up asking here for help.

btw i don't want to use plugin such as svgjs , ... etc

here is my code :
https://jsfiddle.net/z0fd9fqe/13/

HTML:

```
   <svg width="400" height="400" transform="scale(1)">
  <rect id="_svg_editor_background_" fill="#fafafa" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
  <g id="active_group" transform="">
    <rect x="100" y="138" width="200" height="125" stroke-width="2" stroke="red" fill="transparent" class="active-control-border" pointer-events="none"></rect>
    <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://eskipaper.com/images/berries-nature-winter-1.jpg" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="100" y="138.5" width="200px" class=""></image>
    <circle cx="200" cy="200.5" r="6" fill="rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.6)" strokeWidth="1" stroke="slateblue" class="active-control-center" style="null"></circle>
    <circle cx="200" cy="118" r="6" fill="rgba(150, 243, 33, 0.6)" strokeWidth="1" stroke="slateblue" class="active-control-rotator" style="cursor: crosshair;"></circle>
    <circle cx="100" cy="138" r="6" fill="rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.6)" strokeWidth="1" stroke="slateblue" class="active-control-nw" style="cursor: nw-resize;"></circle>
    <circle cx="200" cy="138" r="6" fill="rgba(243, 150, 33, 0.6)" strokeWidth="1" stroke="slateblue" class="active-control-n" style="cursor: n-resize;"></circle>
    <circle cx="300" cy="138" r="6" fill="rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.6)" strokeWidth="1" stroke="slateblue" class="active-control-ne" style="cursor: ne-resize;"></circle>
    <circle cx="300" cy="200.5" r="6" fill="rgba(243, 150, 33, 0.6)" strokeWidth="1" stroke="slateblue" class="active-control-e" style="cursor: e-resize;"></circle>
    <circle cx="300" cy="263" r="6" fill="rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.6)" strokeWidth="1" stroke="slateblue" class="active-control-se" style="cursor: se-resize;"></circle>
    <circle cx="200" cy="263" r="6" fill="rgba(243, 150, 33, 0.6)" strokeWidth="1" stroke="slateblue" class="active-control-s" style="cursor: s-resize;"></circle>
    <circle cx="100" cy="263" r="6" fill="rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.6)" strokeWidth="1" stroke="slateblue" class="active-control-sw" style="cursor: sw-resize;"></circle>
    <circle cx="100" cy="200.5" r="6" fill="rgba(243, 150, 33, 0.6)" strokeWidth="1" stroke="slateblue" class="active-control-w" style="cursor: w-resize;"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
<div id="console">
X: <span id="x">0px</span><br>
Y: <span id="y">0px</span><br>
Width: <span id="width">0px</span><br>
Height: <span id="height">0px</span><br>
Center: <span id="center">0px</span><br>
Rotation: <span id="rot">0deg</span><br>
Rotation Center: <span id="rotcenter">{x:0px,y:0px}</span><br>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #console{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  left:10px;
}
```

JS:

```
//DRAGGING 
$('image').mousedown(function(e){

if (!$(this).is('[class^=active-control-]') && !$(e.target).is('[class^=active-control-]')) {
    var elem = this;
    if ($(this).is('g#active_group')) {
        elem = $(this).find(':not([class^=active-control-])').get(0);
    }

    var pageX0 = e.pageX;
    var pageY0 = e.pageY;

    var init_scale = {width: elem.getBBox().width, height: elem.getBBox().height};
    var init_offset = {x: parseInt($(elem).attr('x')), y: parseInt($(elem).attr('y'))};

    function handle_dragging(e) {

        var x = init_offset.x + (e.pageX - pageX0);
        var y = init_offset.y + (e.pageY - pageY0);


        //change center of rotation to match new element center when dragging
        var trans = transform2Array(elem);
        if (!Object.values(trans).length) {
            trans = transform2Array($(elem).parent());
        }
        var transform = "";
        if (trans.rotate != undefined) {
            var rot_cx = x + init_scale.width / 2;
            var rot_cy = y + init_scale.height / 2;
            transform += "rotate(" + trans.rotate[0] + "," + rot_cx + "," + rot_cy + ")";
        }
        $(elem).attr({x: x, y: y});
        //fix bug rotate +90 drag rotate clear  select& drag => rotate svg element !
        if ($(elem).parent().is('g#active_group'))
            $(elem).parent().attr({transform: transform});
        updateControls($(elem));//update controls to match the new position
    }

    function handle_mouseup(e) {

        $('body')
            .off('mousemove', handle_dragging)
            .off('mouseup', handle_mouseup);
    }

    $('body')
        .on('mouseup', handle_mouseup)
        .on('mousemove', handle_dragging);
}

});
//END OF DRAGGING

$('circle[class^=active-control-]').mousedown(function(md_e) {
  var $control = $(this);
  var $element = $('image:first');
  var control_name = $(this).attr('class').replace('active-control-', '').trim();
  var pageX0 = md_e.pageX;
  var pageY0 = md_e.pageY;
  var init_offset = {
    x: $element.get(0).getBBox().x,
    y: $element.get(0).getBBox().y
  };
  var init_scale = {
    width: $element.get(0).getBBox().width,
    height: $element.get(0).getBBox().height
  };

  console.log('im dragging from ' + control_name);

  function handle_dragging(d_e) {
    if (control_name == 'rotator') {
      //rotate fix source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640642/svg-angle-rotation-by-mousemove-touchmove-bug
      var rx = parseFloat($element.get(0).getBBox().width);
      var ry = parseFloat($element.get(0).getBBox().height);
      var ctm = $element.get(0).getScreenCTM()
      var p = $('svg').get(0).createSVGPoint()

      p.x = d_e.clientX
      p.y = d_e.clientY
      p = p.matrixTransform(ctm.inverse())

      var elem_center_x = init_offset.x + rx / 2;
      var elem_center_y = init_offset.y + ry / 2;
      var radians = Math.atan2(elem_center_x - p.x, elem_center_y - p.y);
      var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 0;

      var new_angle = (getAngle($element) + degree);
      if (new_angle > 360) {
        new_angle -= 360;
      }
      if (new_angle < -360) {
        new_angle += 360;
      }
      $('#console #rot').text(new_angle+"deg");
      $('#console #rotcenter').text(JSON.stringify({x:elem_center_x+"px",y:elem_center_y+"px"}));
      if ($element.parent().is('g#active_group') || $element.is('g#active_group')) {
        $element.parent()
          .attr("transform", "rotate(" + new_angle + "," + elem_center_x + "," + elem_center_y + ")");
      }
    } else {
      makeResize(control_name[0]);
      if (control_name.length == 2) {
        makeResize(control_name[1]);
      }
    }
    updateControls($element);

    function makeResize(direction) {
      var dx = d_e.pageX - pageX0;
      var dy = d_e.pageY - pageY0;
      //do resizing here for each control while image is rotated at any angle
      //change width, height, and coords(x,y)
      switch (direction) {
        case "e":
          $element.attr('width', Math.max(init_scale.width + dx, 10));
          break;
        case "w":
          if ($element.attr('width') != 10)
        $element.attr('x', init_offset.x + dx);
            $element.attr('width', Math.max(init_scale.width - dx, 10));
            break;
        case "s":
          $element.attr('height', Math.max(init_scale.height + dy, 10));
          break;
        case "n": //
          if ($element.attr('height') != 10)
            $element.attr('y', init_offset.y + dy);
          $element.attr('height', Math.max(init_scale.height - dy, 10));
          break;
      }
    }



  }

  function handle_mouseup() {
    $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
    $('body')
      .off('mousemove', handle_dragging)
      .off('mouseup', handle_mouseup);
  }

  $('body')
    .on('mouseup', handle_mouseup)
    .on('mousemove', handle_dragging);
});

function updateControls($element) {
  $element = $($element); //ensure its jquery object 
  var width = parseInt($element.get(0).getBBox().width),
    height = parseInt($element.get(0).getBBox().height),
    data = {
      x: parseInt($element.attr('x')),
      y: parseInt($element.attr('y')),
      rx: width,
      ry: height,
      angle: 0
    };

  var controls = [{
      x: data.x + data.rx / 2,
      y: data.y - 20,
      name: "rotator"
    }, {
      x: data.x + data.rx / 2,
      y: data.y + data.ry / 2,
      name: "center"
    },

    {
      x: data.x,
      y: data.y,
      name: "nw"
    }, {
      x: data.x + data.rx / 2,
      y: data.y,
      name: "n"
    }, {
      x: data.x + data.rx,
      y: data.y,
      name: "ne"
    }, {
      x: data.x + data.rx,
      y: data.y + data.ry / 2,
      name: "e"
    },

    {
      x: data.x + data.rx,
      y: data.y + data.ry,
      name: "se"
    }, {
      x: data.x + data.rx / 2,
      y: data.y + data.ry,
      name: "s"
    }, {
      x: data.x,
      y: data.y + data.ry,
      name: "sw"
    }, {
      x: data.x,
      y: data.y + data.ry / 2,
      name: "w"
    }
  ];
  var bounderAttrs = {
    x: $element.attr('x'),
    y: $element.attr('y'),
    width: $element.attr('width'),
    height: $element.attr('height'),
  };
  $('#console #x').text($element.attr('x')+"px");
  $('#console #y').text($element.attr('y')+"px");
  $('#console #width').text(bounderAttrs.width);
  $('#console #height').text(bounderAttrs.height?bounderAttrs.height+"px":'AUTO SCALED');

  if ($element.parent().is('g#active_group')) {
    $element.parent().find('.active-control-border').attr(bounderAttrs);
    $.each(controls, function(i, o) {
    if(o.name=='center'){
     $('#console #center').text(JSON.stringify({x:o.x+"px",y:o.y+"px"}));
    }
      $element.parent().find('circle.active-control-' + o.name).attr({
        cx: o.x,
        cy: o.y
      });
    });
    return;
  }

}
//get elem angle from transform attribute
function getAngle(elem) {
  var angle = 0;
  var trans = transform2Array(elem);
  if (!Object.values(trans).length) {
    trans = transform2Array(elem.parent());
  }
  if (trans.rotate != undefined) {
    angle = parseFloat(trans.rotate[0]);
  }
  return angle;
}
/**
 * get tranform attribute values as array transform="rotate(x,y,z) scale(x,y)"
 *  return {
 *      rotate:[x,y,z]
 *      scale:[x,y]
 *        }
 */
function transform2Array(elem) {
  var transform = $(elem).attr('transform');
  var transforms = {};
  if (typeof transform !== 'undefined') {
    $.each(transform.split(' '), function(i, o) {
      if (o.length) {
        var trans = o.replace(')', '').split('(');
        transforms[trans[0]] = [];
        var params = trans[1].split(',');
        $.each(params, function(i, o_param) {
          transforms[trans[0]].push(parseFloat(o_param));
        });
      }
    });
  }
  return transforms;
}
updateControls($('image'))
```

;